# How to improve performance on static HTML, UIWebView content

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have `UIWebViews` as cells for my `UITableView`. However, it lags while scrolling due to nature of `UIWebView` being really slow. However, I only use static HTML string as content of `UIWebView`, so it shouldn't have difference with an Image once its loaded, but thats not the case.

Is there any way to improve `UIWebView` performance when using a static HTML string as content?

Comment: uiwebview shouldn't effect the tableview scroll, may be the touches are intercepted by the webvioew. Try disabling the userInteractin for webviews and see if the there is still a lag in the scroll or not.

Comment: Tried it but still laggy.

Comment: can you show your cellForRow method and code of where you reload the webview ?

Comment: Have you tried `WKWebView`? Apple recommends over `UIWebView` if your apps target iOS 8 and above